# Need help understanding why I get dirty reads on code that has same locking during execution

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking, sql-server-2016

CAVEAT: This is legacy code, we know we should be using an actual SQL sequence, the goal here is to understand why one method is providing different results from another because we can't just change to a sequence on the fly at this time.

ISSUE: We are using a single valued table as a sequence object (created pre-2012) to generate and return what needs to be a guaranteed unique, incrementing number. The stored procedure in place works but is churning high CPU and causing severe blocking under high load; The remediation looks as though it should work but does not. CPU and blocking is relieved with new code but we can't seem to be able to prevent dirty reads and this is resulting in duplication.

Here's how the table looks:

```
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.Sequence') is not null
    drop table dbo.Sequence;
create table dbo.Sequence (number int Primary Key); 
insert into dbo.Sequence values (1);
GO
```

This stored proc uses serializable locking and gets accurate results, but it doesn't perform well due to the blocking:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.usp_GetSequence_Serializable @AddSomeNumber INT = 1 AS
BEGIN
declare @return int; --value to be returned and declared within sproc
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
Select @return = number from dbo.Sequence with (updlock) --get initial value plus one
Update dbo.Sequence set number = @return + @AddSomeNumber --increment it
COMMIT TRANSACTION
Select @return + @AddSomeNumber as nextid 
END
GO
```

Here's our faster version that avoids serializable, but it's getting duplicate values back from time to time:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.usp_GetSequence_DefaultIsolationLevel @AddSomeNumber INT = 1 AS
BEGIN
declare @return int; --value to be returned and declared within sproc
update dbo.Sequence set @return = number = number + @AddSomeNumber --we tried interchanging various locking hints with no change in results (likely due to an exclusive being taken already) 
Select @return as nextid
END
GO
```

What can we do to get the faster performance of the second (non-serializable) proc, while avoiding duplicate generated IDs?

Answer (score 0):

In largish databases times will arise when you are unable to avoid deadlocks in your code. The database will *not* always look ahead on all things to avoid contention. In these rare and special cases you can make use of the high performance locking used by SQL Server itself --> [SP_GETAPPLOCK().](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) You can structure your code in such a way to give exclusive access to a critical section in your stored procedure and serialize access to that. `SP_GETAPPLOCK` is definitely not a bad thing when all traditional lock hints fail.

```
DECLARE @MyTimeoutMiliseconds INT =5000--Wait only five seconds max then timeout

BEGIN TRAN
EXEC @LockRequestResult=SP_GETAPPLOCK 'MyCriticalWork','Exclusive','Transaction',@MyTimeoutMiliseconds
IF(@LockRequestResult>=0)BEGIN

            /*
            DO YOUR CRITICAL READS AND WRITES HERE

            You may prefer try finally to release

            */

    COMMIT TRAN -- <--Releases the lock!
END ELSE
    ROLLBACK TRAN --<--Releases the lock!
```

Comment: Hey Ross, How is your solution compare to using 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
--  DO WORK HERE
  COMMIT TRANSACTION

Would your solution help prevent deadlocks?

Comment: Under SERIALIZABLE tx uncommitted data can't be read. The lock above serializes access to a code block, not just the data. Setting the lock timeout gives a bit more fined tuned control to wait 3 minutes for a lock, if you so desired.

Comment: One caveat is that the "code" lock is only within the context of the caller or SP in which it was obtained. Resources will still need to be protected from modifications outside of this context, however, I am betting the code above in the question is not duplicated elsewhere in the system.